# AWS Local CodeBuild Support in PowerShell outputs to Command Prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, cmd, aws-codebuild

I've been following the [instructions for testing AWS CodeBuild locally](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/announcing-local-build-support-for-aws-codebuild/) which has been fine until I run the [codebuild_build.sh script](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/local_builds/codebuild_build.sh) in PowerShell. This is an example of what the command looks like:

```
.\codebuild_build.sh -i dockerimage -a artefactDirectory
```

A Command Prompt window gets opened to run the script, but is closed immediately afterwards, so I don't have enough time to see the generated output.

Is there anything I can do to either keep this window open longer, or ideally output to the PowerShell window?

I've tried piping to file, but this results in an empty file, which I suspect is because the output is put into the cmd window. And I can't spot anything in the script which would cause it to prefer a cmd window over PowerShell.

Here's the codebuild_build.sh AWS script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function allOSRealPath() {
    if isOSWindows
    then
        path=""
        case $1 in
            .* ) path="$PWD/${1#./}" ;;
            /* ) path="$1" ;;
            *  ) path="/$1" ;;
        esac

        echo "/$path" | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/://' -e 's/./\U&/3'
    else
        case $1 in
            /* ) echo "$1"; exit;;
            *  ) echo "$PWD/${1#./}"; exit;;
        esac
    fi
}

function isOSWindows() {
    if [ $OSTYPE == "msys" ]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

function usage {
    echo "usage: codebuild_build.sh [-i image_name] [-a artifact_output_directory] [options]"
    echo "Required:"
    echo "  -i        Used to specify the customer build container image."
    echo "  -a        Used to specify an artifact output directory."
    echo "Options:"
    echo "  -l IMAGE  Used to override the default local agent image."
    echo "  -s        Used to specify source information. Defaults to the current working directory for primary source."
    echo "               * First (-s) is for primary source"
    echo "               * Use additional (-s) in <sourceIdentifier>:<sourceLocation> format for secondary source"
    echo "               * For sourceIdentifier, use a value that is fewer than 128 characters and contains only alphanumeric characters and underscores"
    echo "  -c        Use the AWS configuration and credentials from your local host. This includes ~/.aws and any AWS_* environment variables."
    echo "  -p        Used to specify the AWS CLI Profile."
    echo "  -b FILE   Used to specify a buildspec override file. Defaults to buildspec.yml in the source directory."
    echo "  -m        Used to mount the source directory to the customer build container directly."
    echo "  -e FILE   Used to specify a file containing environment variables."
    echo "            (-e) File format expectations:"
    echo "               * Each line is in VAR=VAL format"
    echo "               * Lines beginning with # are processed as comments and ignored"
    echo "               * Blank lines are ignored"
    echo "               * File can be of type .env or .txt"
    echo "               * There is no special handling of quotation marks, meaning they will be part of the VAL"
    exit 1
}

image_flag=false
artifact_flag=false
awsconfig_flag=false
mount_src_dir_flag=false

while getopts "cmi:a:s:b:e:l:p:h" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i  ) image_flag=true; image_name=$OPTARG;;
        a  ) artifact_flag=true; artifact_dir=$OPTARG;;
        b  ) buildspec=$OPTARG;;
        c  ) awsconfig_flag=true;;
        m  ) mount_src_dir_flag=true;;
        s  ) source_dirs+=("$OPTARG");;
        e  ) environment_variable_file=$OPTARG;;
        l  ) local_agent_image=$OPTARG;;
        p  ) aws_profile=$OPTARG;;
        h  ) usage; exit;;
        \? ) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
        :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
        *  ) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done

if  ! $image_flag
then
    echo "The image name flag (-i) must be included for a build to run" >&2
fi

if  ! $artifact_flag
then
    echo "The artifact directory (-a) must be included for a build to run" >&2
fi

if  ! $image_flag ||  ! $artifact_flag
then
    exit 1
fi

docker_command="docker run -it "
if isOSWindows
then
    docker_command+="-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "
else
    docker_command+="-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "
fi

docker_command+="\"IMAGE_NAME=$image_name\" -e \
    \"ARTIFACTS=$(allOSRealPath $artifact_dir)\""

if [ -z "$source_dirs" ]
then
    docker_command+=" -e \"SOURCE=$(allOSRealPath $PWD)\""
else
    for index in "${!source_dirs[@]}"; do
        if [ $index -eq 0 ]
        then
            docker_command+=" -e \"SOURCE=$(allOSRealPath ${source_dirs[$index]})\""
        else
            identifier=${source_dirs[$index]%%:*}
            src_dir=$(allOSRealPath ${source_dirs[$index]#*:})

            docker_command+=" -e \"SECONDARY_SOURCE_$index=$identifier:$src_dir\""
        fi
    done
fi

if [ -n "$buildspec" ]
then
    docker_command+=" -e \"BUILDSPEC=$(allOSRealPath $buildspec)\""
fi

if [ -n "$environment_variable_file" ]
then
    environment_variable_file_path=$(allOSRealPath "$environment_variable_file")
    environment_variable_file_dir=$(dirname "$environment_variable_file_path")
    environment_variable_file_basename=$(basename "$environment_variable_file")
    docker_command+=" -v \"$environment_variable_file_dir:/LocalBuild/envFile/\" -e \"ENV_VAR_FILE=$environment_variable_file_basename\""
fi

if [ -n "$local_agent_image" ]
then
    docker_command+=" -e \"LOCAL_AGENT_IMAGE_NAME=$local_agent_image\""
fi

if $awsconfig_flag
then
    if [ -d "$HOME/.aws" ]
    then
        configuration_file_path=$(allOSRealPath "$HOME/.aws")
        docker_command+=" -e \"AWS_CONFIGURATION=$configuration_file_path\""
    else
        docker_command+=" -e \"AWS_CONFIGURATION=NONE\""
    fi

    if [ -n "$aws_profile" ]
    then
        docker_command+=" -e \"AWS_PROFILE=$aws_profile\""
    fi

    docker_command+="$(env | grep ^AWS_ | while read -r line; do echo " -e \"$line\""; done )"
fi

if $mount_src_dir_flag
then
    docker_command+=" -e \"MOUNT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY=TRUE\""
fi

if isOSWindows
then
    docker_command+=" -e \"INITIATOR=$USERNAME\""
else
    docker_command+=" -e \"INITIATOR=$USER\""
fi

docker_command+=" amazon/aws-codebuild-local:latest"

# Note we do not expose the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or the AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
exposed_command=$docker_command
secure_variables=( "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=" "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=")
for variable in "${secure_variables[@]}"
do
    exposed_command="$(echo $exposed_command | sed "s/\($variable\)[^ ]*/\1********\"/")"
done

echo "Build Command:"
echo ""
echo $exposed_command
echo ""

eval $docker_command
```

Comment: With out seeing the script, we can't do much. You can attempt to run it with cmd.exe and see if it gives the output to powershell? `cmd.exe -c ".\codebuild_build.sh -i dockerimage -a artefactDirectory"` it all depends on what the "codebuild_build.sh" script is doing, SH usually means linux. I'd also look into what it's doing, maybe it's using write-host instead of write-output etc...

Comment: @RobertCotterman it is an AWS script which is linked to in the question, but here's the url to it: https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/local_builds/codebuild_build.sh . As for running that command it just changes PowerShell to be a cmd.exe instance but doesn't run the command. If I run the command directly in this instance it opens a new cmd.exe window...

Comment: yes, i looked into it, i think it's a docker issue rather than aws, maybe this helps? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2015/12/01/working-with-docker-output-in-powershell/  The reason i believe this, is because it's a docker script you're having issues with

Comment: I've added an [issue to the githubpage](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/239) to see if it is due to how the script operates.

Comment: Please don't link to code, post the relevant parts in the question! Links to external resources become invalid over time, then this post is useless!